# How to display polynomial-time "reduction" symbol?

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for a package where is defined the symbol for polynomial-time reduction that looks like the infinity symbol.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please describe the symbol in more detail. How does it differ from `\infty`? Also, have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: Sipser uses `\le_P` for a polynomial time reduction. For example, Theorem 7.25 (in the first edition), "If $A\le_P B$ and $B\in P$, then $A\in P$."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean `\propto`? I think I've seen that for polynomial-time reduction before...

This answer was brought to you by [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Answer (score 0):

In communication complexity, I've seen `\prec` used.